# Convert string list to dataframe/ aggregate

Tags: string, r

I have string list stock (below)

```
 stock
[[1]]
 [1] "[3,black,sku14422032,Out of stock,21.0,null,null,37RFM2I]"
 [2] "[4,black,sku14421965,Out of stock,21.0,null,null,37RFM2I]"
 [3] "[5,black,sku14421982,Out of stock,21.0,null,null,37RFM2I]"
 [4] "[6,black,sku14421990,Out of stock,21.0,null,null,37RFM2I]"
 [5] "[7,black,sku14422002,In stock,21.0,null,null,37RFM2I]"    
 [6] "[8,black,sku14422013,In stock,21.0,null,null,37RFM2I]"
```

I would like to convert into

```
colour = black
size = 3,4,5,6,7,8
stock = 3-out of stock, 4-out of stock, ...., 8 - In stock
```

I have tried to str_split_fixed but it just splits the first line.

## Any ideas how to rearrange the data .. thanks

originally the string was in this format

```
"stockMatrix = [\n[\"3\",\"black\",\"sku14422032\",\"Out of stock#Sorry, the option you   have selected is out of stock\",\"21.0\",null,null,\"37RFM2I\",\"\"]\n,\n[\"4\",\"black\",\"sku14421965\",\"Out of stock#Sorry, the option you have selected is out of stock\",\"21.0\",null,null,\"37RFM2I\",\"\"]\n,\n[\"5\",\"black\",\"sku14421982\",\"Out of stock#Sorry, the option you have selected is out of stock\",\"21.0\",null,null,\"37RFM2I\",\"\"]\n,\n[\"6\",\"black\",\"sku14421990\",\"Out of stock#Sorry, the option you have selected is out of stock\",\"21.0\",null,null,\"37RFM2I\",\"\"]\n,\n[\"7\",\"black\",\"sku14422002\",\"In stock#\",\"21.0\",null,null,\"37RFM2I\",\"\"]\n,\n[\"8\",\"black\",\"sku14422013\",\"In stock#\",\"21.0\",null,null,\"37RFM2I\",\"\"]\n];"
```

I used below code to clean the string

```
stock = regexpr("stockMatrix(.*?);",srcpage)
stock = regmatches (srcpage,stock)
stock= str_replace_all(stock,'stockMatrix = |;|\\n|"|#|#Sorry, the option you have   selected is out of stock',"")
stock = str_replace_all(stock,"^\\[\\[","[")
stock = str_replace_all(stock,",\\]\\]|\\,]","]")
stock = str_extract_all(stock,"\\[(.*?)\\]")
```

... to get the list level. Is it any better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `strsplit` on the contents of `stock[[1]]`, not `stock`:

```
res.mx <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  strsplit(substr(stock[[1]], 2, nchar(stock[[1]]) - 1), ",")
)
colnames(res.mx) <- c("size", "color", "sku#", "stockstatus", "price", "x", "y", "prod.code")
res.mx
```

This produces:

```
     size color   sku#          stockstatus    price  x      y      prod.code
[1,] "3"  "black" "sku14422032" "Out of stock" "21.0" "null" "null" "37RFM2I"
[2,] "4"  "black" "sku14421965" "Out of stock" "21.0" "null" "null" "37RFM2I"
[3,] "5"  "black" "sku14421982" "Out of stock" "21.0" "null" "null" "37RFM2I"
[4,] "6"  "black" "sku14421990" "Out of stock" "21.0" "null" "null" "37RFM2I"
[5,] "7"  "black" "sku14422002" "In stock"     "21.0" "null" "null" "37RFM2I"
[6,] "8"  "black" "sku14422013" "In stock"     "21.0" "null" "null" "37RFM2I"
```

Comment: You can also pass multiple arguments to `strsplit` like: `do.call(rbind,strsplit(stock[[1]],",|\\[|\\]"))[,-1]`

Comment: @thelatemail, cute way of getting rid of leading and trailing single characters.

Comment: Thanks .. perfect I tried this way but it errored out when i tried to assign col names                                             stock =unlist(stock)
stock = str_split_fixed(stock,',',8)
colnames(stock) = c("size","colour","code","stock","NAinfor","x","y","z","a")